# What is the language whose a function returns value assigned to ret?

Tags: programming-languages, return-value, function-definition

The being returned value is assigned to `ret`, which is a special variable name. One can place another statements following `ret = somevalue` and the function returns the value of `ret` after evaluating all of them even if `return` statement is not put. Maybe the language doesn't have `return` statement. I glanced through its tutorial of the language once but I can not remember the name of that programming language. Thanks

Comment: Modern Pascal can use something like that. The variable holding the result of the function is named (guess...) "result". A function does not need to contain a statement to explicitly exit or return a value, but "exit" can be used to exit prematurely. The returned value is the last assigned to "result".

Comment: @linuxfan Thanks. I didn't know such special variable name "result" feature of Modern Pascal. But Pascal is not the language I want to remember. That is a less known language.